# Smooth transition between any two functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a weird problem. The end use case for this is a computational geometry algorithm being implemented in C#. But here goes the problem.

I have two continuous functions

```
y1 = f(x);
y2 = g(x);
```

I need a third function that is the maximum of y1 and y2, i.e.

```
y3 = max(f(x),g(x));
```

Now my problem here is that whenever f(x) and g(x) cross each other, I get kinks in my max function. Is there any way I can smooth out these kinks ? I saw some posts that do something like this for linear functions using tanh, but I need a more general solution. Also, there is some wiggle room in terms of tolerance so the values don't have to be perfectly accurate, as long as the function is smooth.

Also, I don't know when f(x) and g(x) will cross each other so I need a general function that can take the y1 and y2 values and spit out a smooth function. I am imagining it like a blanket draped over the plots of f and g. If 'f' is higher than 'g' then it will take the value of 'f'. If the functions intersect and 'g' gets higher than 'f', then my blanket function would go through a smooth transition around the point of intersection (like a blanket) and then take the value of 'g'. It should behave like this over the whole domain. Again, any decent approximation of this behavior will work for me.

Is this even possible ? Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance !

Comment: It's possible to get a smooth function, but that function will no longer be $\max(f(x), g(x)$. What do you want the properties of the new function to be?

Comment: What about $\sqrt{f^2+g^2}$ ?

Comment: I am thinking of a new function that will look like a blanket draped over f and g. It will be max(f,g) most of the time, except when f and g intersect (and the max changes), where I want it to have a smooth transition from f to g. And if the functions intersect again, I want the same behavior. I don't mind if the function is not exactly max(f,g) at the point of intersection.

Comment: Here is a 'thinking out loud' idea/answer that might be worthwhile.
I'd go with a Fermi Dirac type distribution to define the smoothness level of the transition when max'es swith from f(x) to g(x) or vice-versa. Defining
$\phi_T(y)=\frac{1}{e^{y/T}+1}$ and where the "temperature" defines the sharpness of the transition in going from $\phi=1$ for $y<0$ to $F=0$ for $y>0$.
now we let $y=f(x)-g(x)$ and $z=g(x)-f(x)$
your smoothed draped tent function would then be $\phi_T(y)g(x)+\phi_T(z)f(x)$

Comment: I had tried this approach in the form of sigmoid functions and It works but not great as it dips below f and g at intersections in order to achieve continuity. Misha Lavrov's answer, which is in the same direction as Yves Daoust's suggestion, works well. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a method that works when $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both positive for all $x$. (We can modify it to work if they are merely bounded below.)

For any $p$, but especially for large $p$, we can take the $p$-norm
$$
   \sqrt[p]{f(x)^p + g(x)^p}.
$$
Just like $\max\{f(x), g(x)\}$, this is guaranteed to be larger than both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. Moreover, if $f(x)$ is much larger than $g(x)$, the $p$-norm will be approximately equal to $f(x)$; the contribution from $g(x)$ is negligible. (The reverse, of course, also holds.)

Taking larger $p$ is better in theory; as $p \to \infty$, the $p$-norm converges to $\max\{f(x), g(x)\}$ pointwise. But in practice, for very large $p$, numerical errors mean that you're just computing the max, with all the flaws that implies. So compromise.

(If $p=2$, we get the function $\sqrt{f(x)^2+g(x)^2}$ suggested by Yves Daoust [in the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2931665/smooth-transition-between-any-two-functions#comment6056092_2931665).)

Comment: This works beautifully and does exactly what I want it to do. In my case, the functions were not strictly positive but they were bounded, so I translated (+y) both functions to make them positive, then applied your solution, then translated the result back down (-y) by the same amount. Thank you !

Comment: I am having to revisit this approach because of a small problem. Like I explained before, I wanted the function to behave like a blanket draped over the two original functions. It works that way in most cases, but I found an exception here - When the values of f and g are equal, the blanket function should also have the same value, but instead it has 2^(1/p) times that value. This creates a strange bump in the otherwise smooth blanket function. Do you have any suggestions on how to get rid of this bump ?

Comment: You cannot get a blanket function $h$ that satisfies all three of (1) differentiable (2) always at least $\max\{f,g\}$ (3) equal to $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ when $f(x)=g(x)$. To see this, consider $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=-x$: properties (2) and (3) imply $h(0)=0$ and $h(x)\ge |x|$, so $h$ cannot be differentiable at $0$. (The derivative from one side, if it exists, is at least $1$; from the other side, at most $-1$.)

Comment: My answer above satisfies (1) and (2) but not (3). To satisfy (2) and (3) but not (1), take $\max\{f,g\}$. To satisfy (1) and (3) but not (2), divide the blanket function by $2^{1/p}$.